# No output - trying to generate report using a parameter in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate my *JasperReports*'s report using a parameter enter in my textfield. It seems that its not working using query with parameter.

Is there any other way to generate the report using parameter from *Java* via *JasperReports API*? I set my report that accept a parameter values as string.

```
public void reportDefault() {
    try {
        String searchreport = searchtextField.getText();
        JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("D:\\reports\\supplierlist.jrxml");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM businfo WHERE busname='%"+searchreport+"%'";
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);      
        jd.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,conn);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp,false);
        jv.viewReport(jp, false);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an SQL syntax error - you have used the wildcard operator `%` with `=` instead of `LIKE`. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: Ok will try.. Thanks